# fresh install of Ubuntu 20 LTS, ctrl alt and super keys not working

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've seen this question posted a couple times with no answer to fixing the problem. I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20 LTS and my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and Super keys are all mapped to <kbd>L Shift</kbd>, Keycode 42. The only language and keyboard I have loaded it US English. I tried loading Gnome-tweaks to fix and that didn't seem to work either. Any info is appreciated thanks

Comment: Did you check out the solutions/workarounds mentioned at [bug #1419563](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1419563)?